# Calculate the gain of the instrumentation amplifier for an input current I

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-source, instrumentation-amplifier, dc-offset, single-supply-op-amp

I'm a little confusing to calculate the gain of my instrumentation amplifier due to different variables and conditions that may influence the gain.

I am creating a project, which needs to inject a **1mA** electric current into the patient's body through 2 electrodes (Current Electrodes), receive this signal through 2 other electrodes (Voltage Electrodes), and amplify this signal, which will be sent to an AD converter.

[image]

The **1 mA** electric current will be produced by a voltage controlled current source, the voltage used in voltage controlled current source will be a sinusoid of **1.98V pp** (With a frequency sweep from **1KHz** to **100KHz**) with the voltage ranging from **-0.99V** to **+0.99V**.

The instrumentation amplifiers used in the current source are of type AD8606 (Analog Devices), with a single supply GND and + 5V.
The instrumentation amplifier will be **INA118** with a **single supply** GND and + 5V (**GND on pin 4 and 5V on pin 7**).
[image]

**Two questions:**

**1)** *For example, for a **gain equal to 2** in the INA118 (**Rg = 50KOhm**), what will be my expected output voltage? Remembering that:*

- *The **gain of the instrumentation amplifier is 2**.*
- *Its power is **single supply + 5V**.*
- *The input will be **1.98V pp in 1mA**.*

**2)** *Another detail*, my AD converter only receives positive signals, so I need to compensate the AC component of the output of my instrumentation amplifier, I intend to do this by **adding + 2.5V (Vdd / 2) on reference pin 5**. *In doing so, what will be the Expected value of my output voltage?*

My biggest problem is to understand the difference between the gain applied to a voltage, and the gain applied to a current, because I am not applying the voltage directly as it is normally done, I am applying through a current source.

The schematic is very similar to this:

[image]

I will use o AD5933 and a HPF (High pass filter or Capacitor Block DC), in the output of the HPF, the voltage will be 1.98V pp (-0.99V to +0.99V). The current source use two opamps (AD8606 with single supply +5V), the outputs of the current source (E1, E2) are the 2 current eletrodes, Z represent the patient's body, and E3, E4 are the two voltage electrodes. The AD5933 is a Sine wave generator and a ADC.

Thank you so much!

Comment: What are the inputs of the in amp connected to? If I understand correctly, the 1.98Vpp waveform is the control voltage for the current source so that's not what the in amp is actually measuring. I assume you have a sense resistor which the in amp is measured the voltage across in order to output a voltage proportional to the current through that resistor.

Comment: Regarding the reference pin, the voltage between the output (pin 6) and the reference (pin 5) will be 2 times the voltage across the inputs. In other words, if there is 1V across the inputs then the output pin will be at 4.5V (the 2.5V reference plus 2V). Be sure to connect the REF pin to a low impedance (e.g. the output of an op amp buffer) -- don't just connect it to a resistor divider.

Comment: I put the schematic in the question, I believe it is now better explained.

Comment: The instrumentation opamp will amplify voltage, the

Comment: The instrumentation amp will amplify the voltage across Z, there is no "current gain" in that stage. If you're having problems distinguishing between voltages and currents then maybe you should consider a different project?